# Like clause not returning all results -- only integers

Tags: where-clause, sql-server-2017

When notes are made into the client info an invoice may be referenced. I am trying to pull a report that marries up an invoice with the related notes.

I struggled for a while since the two columns are using 2 different data types (Varchar and Text). I ended up deciding to use cast to change the data type and import them into a temporary table.
Now that I'm working with the same data type, VarChar, I thought it should be easier. This is the statement I used to create the Temp Table.

```
select c.clientid, c.searchname, cast(nom.ref as varchar(150)) as Ref,
n.CreatedDate, s.name as 'Note Creator', nt.NoteTypeName, n.RecordID, 
cast(n.note as varchar(150)) as note
into #ARNotes
from tblnotes n
join tblclient c on c.clientid=n.RecordID
join tblstaff s on s.staffid=n.CreatedByID
join tblNoteTypes nt on nt.NoteTypeID=n.NoteTypeID
join tblNominal nom on nom.ClientID=c.ClientID
where n.Note is not null
```

All the notes are showing in my temp table somewhat correctly.. It's still raw data that needs the magic where X like Y clause.

So a sample of the data in my new temp table, #ARNotes, would look something like this:

```
Invoice Number              Notes 
1234                        1234 Here is an example
A111                        Another Example A111
B222                        Note Example B222
9876                        Note Example 9876
5432                        No bill referenced
CCCC                        No bill referenced
```

I am using a select statement similar to the one below to query.. my actual final statement will have a bit more logic so that it only pulls invoices that our overdue.

```
select *
from #ARNotes
where note like ('%'+ref+'%')
order by CreatedDate desc
```

The only problem is that is is only pulling where the invoice is a number only. If the invoice number is alphanumerical it is not shown. So if my table was using my sample data, it would only pull these results below. Therefore, it is leaving off A111 and B222 related notes.

```
Invoice Number              Notes 
1234                        1234 Here is an example
9876                        Note Example 9876
```

What am I missing to actually pull all of the values? Or is this even possible?

Comment: It would help if you posted an example of a couple if rows in `#ARNotes`. Also in the `SELECT` above your `WHERE` clause references `notes2`, where is that column, as your `SELECT ... INTO #ARNotes` doesn't have a `notes2` column, as far as I can see.

Comment: I have reformatted the question a little bit to where it makes more sense and shows a sample similar to my temporary #AR table is. 
Also notes2 was me just tweaking it ever so slightly since the column name was notes, i renamed the results of that column to differentiate it.. just to double check I wasn't doing anything just plain dumb.

Answer (score 1):

After further review, I found that the data with the invoice number had trailing spaces. Those that were integer only were imported from our old system and were not assigned the new ref/invoice number with the new system.
I adjusted my import into the temp table to

```
select c.clientid, c.searchname, **rTRIM(CAST(nom.ref AS varchar(150))) AS Ref,**,
n.CreatedDate, s.name as 'Note Creator', nt.NoteTypeName, n.RecordID, 
cast(n.note as varchar(150)) as note
into #ARNotes
from tblnotes n
join tblclient c on c.clientid=n.RecordID
join tblstaff s on s.staffid=n.CreatedByID
join tblNoteTypes nt on nt.NoteTypeID=n.NoteTypeID
join tblNominal nom on nom.ClientID=c.ClientID
where n.Note is not null
```

Comment: I'd consider some form of data cleansing if possible to remove whitespaces, unless they valid and required. A one off cleanse will negate the need to trim data on every execution and probably make the query slightly more efficient if you are dealing with large volumes